# Javascript: How to remove symbols that do not represent number

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I got the following string in UTF-8 encoding:

> &#8364 ;64.95

The "&#8364" represents a Euro currency sign. I want to write code that erases all UTF-8 characters that are not '.' and/or a digit. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Is this extracted from an html file?

Comment: Yes. I write a script that reads external websites and collects data from them.

Comment: Ok, well that is an html escaped character, not UTF-8 encoding. If you just want to erase these rather than unescape them then something like `str.replace(/&#\d*;/gm, '')` would probably suffice.

Comment: OK. What does &# represent in UTF-8 ?

Comment: It would represent `&#` I would image, but in html https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_13.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are scraping HTML and what you have posted is an example of [an escaped character for use in HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML). If you are not interested in unescaping this character, but just removing it, then something as simple as the following should suffice.

```js
const str = '&#8364;64.95';
const after = str.replace(/&#\d*;/gm, '');
console.log(after);
```

Comment: what does "/gm" mean ?

Comment: global and multi-line : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions